# Regex for alphanumberic with / or -

Tags: regex

The regex should match alphabets or numbers with `/` or `-` in between them but should not start or end with `/` or `-`

I tried this using [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) but does not work

`[a-zA-Z0-9]+[/|-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current regex has the following problems :

- it matches multiple `/` and `-`, but only in one spot (e.g. will match `0123/-/-456` but not `0123/456/789`
- it also matches `|`, which you don't need to use in a `[character class]`
- it matches up until the `end of the string$`, but doesn't match from `^the start of the string` (e.g. it would match `foo0123/456`, although it wouldn't match `0123/456foo`)

You can use the following regex that [Avinash Raj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297613/) proposed :

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[/-][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

The first point it fixed by putting both the character classe matching slashes and dashes and the one matching alnum characters inside a `(?:non-capturing group)` which we can quantify with `*` to specify it can occur any number of time. This group will match any number of slash or dash followed by alnum characters.

The other two points are straightforward, we remove the useless `|` and add a `^` at  the start of the regex.